# Printing contents with a specific range with Awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a text file containing:

```
Location 1  40.733596   -74.003139  
Location 2  43.758102   -73.975734  
Location 3  41.732456   -74.003755              
Location 4  42.345907   -71.087001
```

where the first column is just a location count, the second column represents the latitude and third represents the longitude.

I'm trying to write an awk command to only print out the location within a specific latitude and longitude range.

```
awk -F '\t' '$2>40,$2<=42,$3>=-71,$3<=74 {print $1,$2,$3}'LatLon.txt
```

in the pattern segment of the awk command I'm trying to specify the range for the column 2 and column 3 where it prompts bash to only print the location within 40-42 lat and -71 to -74 lon range.

I'm getting an error mentioning:

```
awk: bailing out at source line 1
```

due to the pattern segment of my awk line. How do i properly specify the range?

Comment: change the `,`s to `&&` (untested). If needed, you can also use `||`. Good luck.

Comment: None of the four lines meet the four requirements in your command.

Comment: I find ranges are more readable like this `(40 < $2 && $2 < 42) && (-74 < $3 && $3 < -71)` -- easier to read what the min and max values are

Comment: and since you're printing the whole line, you don't need the action block `{print $1, $2, $3}` at all - printing the current record is awks default behavior given a true condition.

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
awk -F '\t' '$2>40,$2<=42,$3>=-71,$3<=74 {print $1,$2,$3}'LatLon.txt
```

This has a few errors in it:

- You need to combine conditionals with `&&` rather than commas
- Your test on `$3` won't pass when corrected
  since you're asking for values between -71 and 74 yet all given values are lower than -71
- You need a space between the awk code and your file.

This code should work for you:

```
awk -F '\t' '(40 < $2 && $2 <= 42) && (-74 <= $3 && $3 <= -71)' LatLon.txt
```

You may notice the lack of an action here.  The default action is to print the line as-is, so this is roughly comparable to the action you gave (though `{print $1,$2,$3}` re-concatenates those fields using `OFS` which defaults to a space rather than a tab; you could do `OFS="\t"; print $1,$2,$3` to preserve that or just `print $0` which is what happens by default without an action.)

The parentheses are technically unnecessary.  They are provided for legibility.